# Why does a non-constexpr std::integral_constant work as a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

My question is why the following code is valid C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

std::tuple<const char *, const char *> tuple("Hello", "world");

std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> zero;
std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1> one;

template<typename T> const char *
lookup(T n)
{
  // I would expect to have to write this:
  //   return std::get<decltype(n)::value>(tuple);

  // But actually this works:
  return std::get<n>(tuple);
}

int
main()
{
  std::cout << lookup(zero) << " " << lookup(one) << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, I'm happy to be able to program this way.  Moreover, I understand that `std::integral_constant` has a `constexpr` conversion operator.  However, the parameter `n` to `lookup` is not constexpr, so I'm confused as to how a non-static method on a non-constexpr object (even if the method itself is constexpr) can possibly return a compile-time constant.

Of course, we happen to know in this case that the body of the conversion operator doesn't look at the runtime value, but nothing in the type signature guarantees that.  For example, the following type obviously doesn't work, even though it, too, has a constexpr conversion operator:

```
struct bad_const {
  const std::size_t value;
  constexpr bad_const(std::size_t v) : value(v) {}
  constexpr operator std::size_t() const noexcept { return value; }
};

bad_const badone(1);
```

Is there some extra property of methods that they are considered differently if they ignore the implicit `this` argument?

Comment: Language version and language lawyer tag would be helpful here.

Comment: Note that unfortunately currently it will fail with a reference, e.g. `const T& n` instead of `T n`. Although nothing changes about the conversion, this exception for references is specifically specified like that, but will hopefully be fixed at some point (https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/973).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Of course, we happen to know in this case that the body of the conversion operator doesn't look at the runtime value, but nothing in the type signature guarantees that.

Correct. What you are missing is the fact that this doesn't matter.

When a function is called during constant expression evaluation, the compiler checks whether the function is `constexpr`. If it's not `constexpr`, then the enclosing evaluation fails to yield a constant expression.

But if it *is* `constexpr`, then the compiler executes its body at compile time and checks whether anything in its body disqualifies the enclosing evaluation from being a constant expression.

So in the case of the conversion operator of `std::integral_constant`, the compiler, executing its body at compile time, sees that it simply returns the value of the template parameter, which is fine.

If the compiler were evaluating a `constexpr` member function of some other type, which reads a non-`const` non-static data member of the object (and the object is not `constexpr`), then the compiler, at that point, would determine that the enclosing evaluation is not a constant  expression.

It's a bit upsetting that when you see a function that has been declared `constexpr`, this tells you nothing about *which* evaluations of that function yield constant expressions, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score -3):

In `std::get<n>()` the `n` needs to be a `size_t` but you pass a `std::integral_constant<...>`. So the compiler checks if there is an implicit conversion from one to the other, which attempts to call `std::integral_constant<...>::operator size_t()`. As it happens that is exactly the operator your `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> zero;` has. So everything works out fine type wise.

But you asked why this is a compile-time constant: The `operator size_t()` returns the `static constexpr T value = v;`. So it doesn't matter if the `integral_constant` itself is const or not. It has no influence on the returned constant.

Comment: You are missing the point of the question, which is why conversion works at compile-time.  Everything you write about the conversion operator also applies to `bad_const`, but you cannot supply a non-constexpr `bad_const` as the template argument to `std::get`.

Comment: @user3188445 I noticed myself and refined my answer.